# Creating an UIImageView on UIButton click

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uibutton, uiimage, ios6

I have a button setup in one class and on clicking it, I am calling a method which is in another class and in that method I have setup code for UIImageView.

the method is getting called, But somehow the ImageView doesnt seems to get created, I dont understand why, And therefore I cannot add any Image to that ImageView.

Here's some code of what I am trying to do:

In my first viewControllerClass I have this method which fires on a button click:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {

    [secondViewController createNewImageView];
}
```

and then in the second viewController I am calling that createNewImageView method, in which I am creating an ImageView at runtime:

```
-(void)createNewImageView {

    newImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,100, 100, 100)];
    newImageView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor yellowColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4];
    [self.otherNewView addSubview:newImageView];
}
```

But somehow the ImageView is not getting added on my view, Any Ideas why this is happening ?

What am i missing here ..?

Thanks for your time :)

**EDIT : The class which holds the button is UIPopOverController.**

Comment: What is otherNewView? Is it nil?

Comment: No, Its an UIView I have added that using the IB. Its not nil. If a add the ImageView in ViewDidLoad method, Is gets added fine. 
But on button click, Nop ..!

Comment: add a print to createNewImageView, click and see if it called

Comment: Yes, I added a NSLog to check, And it is getting called.

Comment: It is not created or can say created but replaced as when you call the method in first controller and then load the second view controller so when you try to create the image view the otherNewView is not actually there

Comment: just try to load the secondview first and on the viewWillAppear method call create the imageview and add it to otherNewView and it will work

Comment: Actually the firstViewController class which holds the button is UIPopOverController. 
I missed to mention it in my question, My bad. 
I am editing my question.

Comment: In my class which holds the button, I have set up a UIScrollView and on that I have placed a button,  I am using This class as UIPopOverController. It(Class) appears on a barButtonItem click event similar to photoLibrary that appears in iPad

Answer (score 0):

Have you allocated `secondViewController` before doing,

```
[secondViewController createNewImageView];
```

I think you have not created an object for `secondViewController`. 
So before calling the function create the object for the class.

Comment: Thanks,But I have created the object for my class because the method is getting called. Any ways i ended up using a simple work around to achieve my purpose, I am now adding my ImageView on a button click event which I am using to open the PopOverController.
But thanks All for the inputs :)